# Developer Workflow Management

Tags: team, project-management

So I'm currently working alone on my software project and I was thinking about getting some people to work with me.

Now my question is based on security but also accessibility. How can I manage the developers and just let them work but also check what they are doing and don't have the risk that something breaks even tho I have backups. (If they would have server access etc.)

I was thinking about a GitHub repository where the developers push and a docker container gets automatically built and deployed. In this case, the developers won't have access to the server but are still able to do their work.

I'm thankful for every opinion and every tip. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: This was [closed on Software Engineering due to needing more focus](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/435581/developer-workflow-management). It still needs more focus, and is arguably off-topic here anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is not about workplace people issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A repo of some sort is essential, with a trunk development process (no pushes to trunk unless the change passes tests and any code reviews you put in place). No server access for anyone except very well trusted associates (so, no one). It all seems like you're on the correct path.